# What is the correct way to define a PK with an identity in Entity Framework

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

What's the correct way of defining a PK with an identity in EF 5.0 (code-first)?

I started using `[Key]` which seems to create the key with an identity but I have seen a lot of  examples that use

```
[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
```

Does it matter either way?? Is the 2nd option better as its more descriptive etc..??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short Answer:**

`[Key]` by itself is enough, you don't even need it if you followed the conventions correctly. On the other hand, `[Key]` is semantically equal to `[Key(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]`, they are the same, they are equal to the bone, no difference whatsoever.

**Long Answer:**

- There is a situation where you are **forced** to use
  `[Key(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` and that happens when your
  primary key is a `Guid` because you need to let the database and EF
  know that it should generate a value for that, they only know to do
  so when the primary key is an `int`.
- `[Key(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]` is used when the primary key is
  to be inserted explicity by the user, for example the primary key is
  the social security number *(the db shouldn't generate this one)*.
- Last situation, `[Key(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]` is **only**
  to be used when **there is already** a column in a table that is
  computed, such as when you have a Fullname column in a table
  that is computed by combining the Firstname and Lastname columns,
  this option **must** be used **only** when you are mapping to an
  **existing** database.

Most of this information is taken from the book [Programming Entity Framework : Code First](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449312942).